# Flutter platform channels pass "multi-data" to windows function

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-windows, flutter-platform-channel

I am testing the [Platform-Channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-c-plus-plus-tab#codec) with the windows visual studio 2022.

I can pass the single value from the flutter UI while I get the battery value, but I want to send multi-data from flutter to the windows code.
Here is mine test code which I follow the flutter tutorial:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const MethodChannel platform =
      MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/battery');

  String _batteryLevel = 'Unknown battery level.';
  int value = 100;
  Future<void> _getBatteryLevel(int fluval) async {
    String batteryLevel;
    try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel', fluval);
      batteryLevel = 'Battery level at $result % .';
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      batteryLevel = "Failed to get battery level: '${e.message}'.";
    }
    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _getBatteryLevel(100);
              },
              child: const Text('Get Battery Level'),
            ),
            Text(_batteryLevel),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the windows side:

```
void initMethodChannel(flutter::FlutterEngine* flutter_instance) {
    const static std::string channel_name("samples.flutter.dev/battery");
    auto channel =
        std::make_unique<flutter::MethodChannel<>>(
            flutter_instance->messenger(), channel_name,
            &flutter::StandardMethodCodec::GetInstance());
    channel->SetMethodCallHandler(
        [](const flutter::MethodCall<>& call,
            std::unique_ptr<flutter::MethodResult<flutter::EncodableValue>> result) {

                // cheack method name called from dart
                if (call.method_name().compare("getBatteryLevel") == 0) {
                    int battery_level = GetBatteryLevel();
                    const auto* flu_value = std::get_if<int>(call.arguments());
                    std::cout << typeid(flu_value).name() << std::endl;

                    if (!flu_value) {
                        result->Error("Missing required type parameter","Expected int");
                    }
                    std::cout << "From Flutter: " << *flu_value << std::endl;

                    if (battery_level != -1) {
                        result->Success(battery_level);
                    }
                    else {
                        result->Error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    result->NotImplemented();
                }
        });
}
```

if I want to send multi-data like this:

```
Future<void> _getBatteryLevel(int fluval, int data2,...,...) ...
```

How should I do or parse these two values fluval and data2 when call once invokeMethod?

Any examples that I can reference? or tips for the **Windows** UI design?

I try to search but the most answer is for the Android or IOS app, and the android answer is using `call.argument("value")` which you can choose specific data value to use but the windows only has `call.arguments();` function call, I don't know how to get the specific data I want.

============================================================
[Update]
From the @Richard tips and example,
I made a test and it works, thanks @Richard!

Here is the Flutter UI example code: (inside the Stateful Widget State class), fluval= 100, fluval2 = 87

```
  String _getBackV1 = 'Unknown Value 1.';
  String _getBackV2 = 'Unknown Value 2.';
  int value = 100;
  Future<void> _testMapPassValue(int fluval, int fluval2) async {
    String backValue1, backValue2;
    try {
      final Map<String, dynamic>? getReply = await platform
          .invokeMapMethod<String, dynamic>('testPass',
              <String, dynamic>{"fluval": fluval, "fluval2": fluval2});
      backValue1 = "Get Back Value 1 from windows: ${getReply!["fluval"]}";
      backValue2 = "Get Back Value 2 from windows: ${getReply!["fluval2"]}";
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      backValue1 = "Failed to get Value 1: '${e.message}'.";
      backValue2 = "Failed to get Value 2: '${e.message}'.";
    }
    setState(() {
      _getBackV1 = backValue1;
      _getBackV2 = backValue2;
    });
  }
```

At the Windows side example code:

```
using flutter::EncodableList;
using flutter::EncodableMap;
using flutter::EncodableValue;
constexpr char testMapPassValue[] = "testPass";

constexpr char passKey1[] = "fluval";
constexpr char passKey2[] = "fluval2";
```

The method call handler:

```
if (call.method_name().compare(testMapPassValue) == 0) {
  const auto* getArguments_flu = std::get_if<flutter::EncodableMap>(call.arguments());
  assert(getArguments_flu);
  return Flu_2_Win_MethodHandler(*getArguments_flu, std::move(result));
}

void Flu_2_Win_MethodHandler(
    const EncodableMap& args, std::unique_ptr<flutter::MethodResult<>> result) {
    int wins2fluValue1;
    int wins2fluValue2;
    EncodableMap win2fluMap;

    const auto* flu2winsValue1 =
        std::get_if<int>(ValueOrNull(args, passKey1));
    if (!flu2winsValue1) {
        return result->Error("argument_error",
            std::string(passKey1) + " argument missing");
    }
    wins2fluValue1 = *flu2winsValue1;
    std::cout << "From Flutter value1: " << *flu2winsValue1 << std::endl;
    wins2fluValue1 = wins2fluValue1 + 10;
    std::cout << "After calculate value1: " << wins2fluValue1 << std::endl;

    const auto* flu2winsValue2 =
        std::get_if<int>(ValueOrNull(args, passKey2));
    if (!flu2winsValue2) {
        return result->Error("argument_error",
            std::string(passKey2) + " argument missing");
    }
    wins2fluValue2 = *flu2winsValue2;
    std::cout << "From Flutter value1: " << *flu2winsValue2 << std::endl;
    wins2fluValue2 = wins2fluValue2 + 20;
    std::cout << "After calculate value2: " << wins2fluValue2 << std::endl;

    win2fluMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("fluval", wins2fluValue1));
    win2fluMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("fluval2", wins2fluValue2));
    
    return result->Success(std::move(EncodableValue(win2fluMap)));
}
```

and the final result:

[image: FlutterUI Result]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass a single entity as argument or result, but that entity can be any of the supported types (whether primitive - int, double, etc - or complex - list or map).

The mapping between Dart and C++ (native for Windows) types is:

```
// std::monostate       -> null
// bool                 -> bool
// int32_t              -> int
// int64_t              -> int
// double               -> double
// std::string          -> String
// std::vector<uint8_t> -> Uint8List
// std::vector<int32_t> -> Int32List
// std::vector<int64_t> -> Int64List
// std::vector<float>   -> Float32List
// std::vector<double>  -> Float64List
// EncodableList        -> List
// EncodableMap         -> Map
```

(see `encodable_value.h`)

So, to send your two integers (`fluval` and `data2`) you could choose to put them in a Dart list (i.e. `<int>[123, 456]`) or a Dart map (i.e. `{'fluval':123, 'data2':456}`). At the native end, arguments will be either an `EncodableList` or `EncodableMap`.

Here's an example of how a complex Dart structure would appear at the native end:

```
//   {
//     'flag': true,
//     'name': 'Thing',
//     'values': [1, 2.0, 4],
//   }
// would correspond to:
//   EncodableValue(EncodableMap{
//       {EncodableValue("flag"), EncodableValue(true)},
//       {EncodableValue("name"), EncodableValue("Thing")},
//       {EncodableValue("values"), EncodableValue(EncodableList{
//                                      EncodableValue(1),
//                                      EncodableValue(2.0),
//                                      EncodableValue(4),
//                                  })},
//   })
```

The [camera](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/camera/camera_windows/windows/camera_plugin.cpp) plugin has some example usage (to get the arguments as a map):

```
const auto* arguments = std::get_if<flutter::EncodableMap>(method_call.arguments());
```

In the same file, check out the two utility functions:

```
// Looks for |key| in |map|, returning the associated value if it is present, or
// a nullptr if not.
const EncodableValue* ValueOrNull(const EncodableMap& map, const char* key) {
  auto it = map.find(EncodableValue(key));
  if (it == map.end()) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  return &(it->second);
}

// Looks for |key| in |map|, returning the associated int64 value if it is
// present, or std::nullopt if not.
std::optional<int64_t> GetInt64ValueOrNull(const EncodableMap& map,
                                           const char* key) {
  auto value = ValueOrNull(map, key);
  if (!value) {
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  if (std::holds_alternative<int32_t>(*value)) {
    return static_cast<int64_t>(std::get<int32_t>(*value));
  }
  auto val64 = std::get_if<int64_t>(value);
  if (!val64) {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
  return *val64;
}
```

and their typical usage:

```
  const auto* camera_name =
      std::get_if<std::string>(ValueOrNull(args, kCameraNameKey));

  auto camera_id = GetInt64ValueOrNull(args, kCameraIdKey);
```

Comment: Thank you Richard! I will follow the example and do a simple test first!

Answer (score 0):

I use this to pass argument from flutter to cpp.

```
const auto* arguments = std::get_if<flutter::EncodableMap>(call.arguments());

auto arg1 = (arguments->find(EncodableValue("x")))->second;
auto arg2 = (arguments->find(EncodableValue("y")))->second;
```

Flutter Side:-

```
  await platform.invokeMethod('setCursorPos', <String, dynamic>{"x": x, "y": y});
```